# Working on a C program to count characters, words, sentences, lines, or all the above.

Tags: c, function

We are asked to create a program that provides a table in which the user can choose whether to count characters, words, sentences, lines, or all the above. This requires a separate function for each utility. I have the line counter working perfectly, but for some reason, the character counter function keeps returning 0. The program is incomplete, but I am getting very frustrated with the character counter.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define WHT_SPC\
         (cur == ' ' || cur == '\n' || cur == '\t')

int countLines(sp1);
int wordCounter(sp1);
int characterCounter(sp1);
int sentenceCounter (sp1);

int main()
{
    int lineCount = 0;
    int wordCount = 0;
    int characterCount= 0;
    int sentenceCount = 0;
    char filename[100];
    FILE* sp1;


    printf("Enter Filename to be read: ");
    gets(filename);
    sp1 = fopen(filename,"r");


    lineCount = countLines(sp1);
    characterCount = characterCounter(sp1);


    printf("Number of Lines: %d\n",lineCount);
    printf("Number of Characters: %d\n",characterCount);

    fclose(sp1);
    return 0;
}


int countLines(sp1)
{
    int curCh;
    int preCh;
    int countLn = 0;

    while ((curCh = fgetc(sp1)) != EOF)
    {
        if (curCh == '\n')
            countLn++;
        preCh = curCh;
    }
    if (preCh != '\n')
        countLn++;


    return countLn;
}

int characterCounter(sp1)
{
    int chr;
    int countCh = 0;

    while ((chr = fgetc(sp1)) != EOF)
    {
        if (chr != 'n' && chr != ' ')
            countCh++;
    }

    return countCh;
}
```

I understand the lack of comments is not ideal, but my problem is very specific. Not looking for answers just some advice to kind of point me in the right direction.

Comment: You didn't [`rewind()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/rewind) the file before embarking on the character count. And the lack of comments has nothing to do with this code not even compiling (no type for `sp1` in any of the function decls/defs).

Comment: thank you very much. i know comments does not have anything to do with the compiling, but its just good practice i was told.

Comment: It would be better to make only one pass over the file and count characters, words, and lines, etc.  Rewinding and reading the file again is inefficient.

Comment: @starkI know it would be better but the assignment that was given he wants us to do it this way. Believe me, I argued saying that the assignment itself is not very realistic, but what can you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sp1` is a structure that holds, among other things, your position in the file you are reading. After the inner loop of `countLines()`, this field will point the end of the file. You will need to call `rewind(sp1);` before performing other read operations on this same stream, so it will work on its beginning again. 
Don't hesitate to take a look at [`man rewind`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/rewind.3p.html)!

Comment: thank you very much for your feedback. The rewind function is new to me so I just have one question on it. Do I have to rewind it at the end of every function or the beginning of each?

Comment: Nevermind just tested it out and saw you could put it before each function, and it works properly. Thank you again.

Comment: Do not hesitate to mark your question as closed now that everything works ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`fgetc()` increments the filepointer.

Thus `characterCounter()` caled after `countLines()` has to return 0 as the first character it encounters is EOF.

Try using `fseek(sp1, 0L, SEEK_SET)` before `characterCounter()`.